# How to adjust the height in of an input so it matches the submit's height

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am currently using Foundation to redesign a site. The redesigned website will have a searh bar on the header, the problem is Im trying to get the input and the button to have the same height without using any kind of fixed-height since this layout has to be responsive. 
 Here is the code I have:

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="small-9 columns">
        <div class="radius panel">

        <form>
          <div class="row collapse">

            <div class="small-10 columns left" >
              <input type="text" />
            </div>

            <div class="small-2 columns right tiny" >
              <a href="#" class="button expand">Search</a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  <!-- End Search Bar -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by fixed-height? Do percentages count? How does this affect responsiveness?

Comment: I meant I dont want to use pixels. (% are OK)

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just use `height`. The trick to using percentages is you have to specify *somewhere* the absolute height, either by using pixels or by using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. Percentages have to be based on some parent's height, or else when you say 50%, 50% of what?

See this <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KHST8/1/)</kbd> for example:

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
form {
    position: relative;
    height: 50%;
}
input[type="text"] {
    height: 100%;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    height: 100%;
}
```

I specified the height of the body, which is set as `position: absolute` at `100%`. This is the standard under which all descendants will base upon. Now, `form` takes 50% of that and the two inputs take up the entire height of the form.

Of course, you probably don't want to specify the height of the body in your case, but it might as well be `.row`.

You might think, well I don't want to specify a height higher up, but I want the children to be percentage-based. But if you think about it, the parents have heights **based on the children** so that it can wrap all of them. If you're not going to specify a height, then that is all the parent's height is based on. If you want the child's height to be 50% of the parent's height, and say there is only that one child, then the parent's height must shrink as well, which will just make it recursive and impossible.

Comment: i have tried using % following your example above, however Im still getting the same results. The input's height remains lower than the button's.

Comment: By how much? It's just a margin/padding issue then

Comment: it's already fixed. Turns out Foundation has a postfix class that solves this problem.Thanks!